# AngularJs - Multiple services sharing same singular datasource. Design pattern issues

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I am attempting to come up with the best design pattern for the following problem.

Lets say I have a block and in a block I can have rows.  Inside said row, I can have columns and inside said column, I can have widgets.

Now lets say everything that makes up the internals of a block is not stored in a relationship database and is instead stored off as someplace as JSON. Meaning when I update a row, column or widget, I have to call some endpoint that will save the entire block as opposed to saving just a row, column, or widget.

Typically I would have one service to handle CRUD operations.  In the particular situation though, my one service is becoming unmanageable.  This is because not only do I have to service a "block", I also have to perform various logic every time a row, column or widget is altered, followed by updating/deleting/add a block to wherever we are storing the JSON representation.

That being said, I am looking for way to abstract some of this logic across multiple services.  With then having the ability to have these services all share one data point.  For example...

BlockService

-- RowService

-- ColumnService

-- WidgetService

BlockService has all the dependencies listed below it. But, because I need to update a block everytime a row, column or widget is updated, there is no (at least as far as I know) way to reach back up to the BlockService from any of the services (Row, Column, Widget) BlockService depends on.

Which all leads be to believe I might be thinking about this design pattern incorrectly.

How would one design a set of services that all service the same singular set of data?

Best,

Chad

Comment: In this case, the widget column and row services all update the block. Because of this, i would instead swap the order of your dependancies to have row column and widget all depend on BlockService, and when each of them finish their operation, they call the BlockService to do the final save.

Comment: Of course, you then realize that widget column and row each cause a save, and you would rather perform all three before finally hitting the block service. Seems like you need some kind of intermediary to control the flow between these 4 services. Or control it within the controller.

Comment: Restangular simplifies a lot of this

Comment: @KevinB - Lets say I have it pattern like so...

(RowService -> BlockService, ColumnService --> BlockService, WIdgetService -> BlockService) ...

By saying there are three BlockService dependencies, is Angular smart enough to insure there is only a singular BlockService being used across all three services?

If BlockService needs to initialize the initial data-set, how would one do this with three dependencies in play?

Comment: Also, for clarity, the updates do not bubble up the relation chain.  If a widget is saved, it does not mean a column is saved, then a row, followed by the block.  If either is altered, a block is then saved that has the alter data.

Comment: There will be only one instance of the service. I use the same technique to handle the "Cart" of an ecommerce application. The same "CartService" is included in the navigation, the store, and the checkout controllers so that they all access the same cart with methods to modify the cart.

Comment: @KevinB - What about getting a data-set.  Lets say I am dealing with x-amount of blocks and I need to reach into the a block-collection to make logic choices on how to update a singular block.  In this pattern, where would the singular block-collection be initialized and live?  In your case, I would imagine you have a collection of items in your cart....

Comment: You could make it part of the block service, for example, BS.loadBlocks() would load the blocks into a collection of blocks, then your row widget and column services would interact with a specific block from that collection, probably by ID.

Comment: the collection of blocks would reside as a property of the service, or as a private collection that is accessed via service methods.

Comment: @KevinB - If RowService relies on Blockservice to set a data collection, how do you insure BlockService has set that collection beforew RowService tries to access it?

Comment: you could make getting a block from the collection a method that returns a promise that isn't resolved until the collection is set. There's just so many options available in this case, it's easy for me to just spit out an idea, implementing it is a different story entirely.

Comment: @KevinB - I do appreciate your ideas.  I am playing them to see what works in my situation.  In regards to putting a method in side the "BlocksService" that returns a promise, if multiple services that have the BlockService as a dep are calling said method, are they all waiting for the same getter method to return?

Comment: Its gets a bit mixed up in my head when considering initialization versus a getter.

Comment: Look at it this way. Your collection, IS a promise (or, should be.) When a getter is used, you use .then() to create a new promise based on the result of the collection filtered down to the requested block.

Comment: Here's a sample: http://pastebin.com/t3FpZ1xB not tested in any way of course.

Comment: @KevinB - I was able to piece it together with all of your advice.   Much appreciated...